# Using getopt_long() second pass does not work

Tags: c

I wanted to use `getopt_long()` twice in a routine so that a verbosity flag can be set before parsing everything else but somehow the second call of the function does not process the arguments as expected. Here is a simplified code that demonstrates the issue. Anyone has any clues?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

static void processInput(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int k;
    int verbose = 0;
    struct option long_options[] = {
        {"help"   , no_argument, NULL, 'h'},
        {"verbose", no_argument, NULL, 'v'},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
    // Construct short_options from long_options
    char str[1024] = "";
    for (k = 0; k < sizeof(long_options) / sizeof(struct option); k++) {
        struct option *o = &long_options[k];
        snprintf(str + strlen(str), 1023, "%c%s", o->val, o->has_arg == required_argument ? ":" : (o->has_arg == optional_argument ? "::" : ""));
    }
    // First pass: just check for verbosity level
    int opt, long_index = 0;
    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, (char * const *)argv, str, long_options, &long_index)) != -1) {
        printf("Processing %c\n", opt);
        switch (opt) {
            case 'v':
                verbose++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //
    // Add verbose flag here to show something while setting up
    //

    // Second pass: now we go through all of them.
    long_index = 0;
    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, (char * const *)argv, str, long_options, &long_index)) != -1) {
        printf("Processing %c\n", opt);
        switch (opt) {
            case 'h':
                printf("Help text here\n");
                break;
            case 'v':
                // Add a dummy line here so that '-v' does not trigger the default task
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "I don't understand: -%c   optarg = %s\n", opt, optarg);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                break;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char **argv) {

    processInput(argc, argv);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The global variable `optind` is increased to `argc` by the end of `getopt_long()` routine so the second pass simply would not go further. In order to have the function reprocess everything from the beginning again, the global variable `optind` needed to be reset. So, add

```
// Second pass: now we go through all of them.
optind = 1;
long_index = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated is the man page of [getopt_long](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long) :

> The variable optind is the index of the next element to be processed in argv. The system initializes this value to 1. The caller can reset it to 1 to restart scanning of the same argv, or when scanning a new argument vector.

So you have to set optind to 1 before the second pass.

```
    // Second pass: now we go through all of them.
    optind = 1;
    long_index = 0;
    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, (char * const *)argv, str, long_options, &long_index)) != -1) {
        printf("Processing %c\n", opt);
        switch (opt) {
            case 'h':
                printf("Help text here\n");
                break;
            case 'v':
                // Add a dummy line here so that '-v' does not trigger the default task
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "I don't understand: -%c   optarg = %s\n", opt, optarg);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Little warning : Further on the man, there is this note :

> A program that scans multiple argument vectors, or rescans the same vector more than once, and wants to make use of GNU extensions such as '+' and '-' at the start of optstring, or changes the value of POSIXLY_CORRECT between scans, must reinitialize getopt() by resetting optind to 0, rather than the traditional value of 1. (Resetting to 0 forces the invocation of an internal initialization routine that rechecks POSIXLY_CORRECT and checks for GNU extensions in optstring.)

So be carefull and choose what it most suit your situation.